# How to make an installer with update manager for my Java application?

Tags: java, javafx, deployment, updates, executable

I recently resumed my project after taking a break, particularly after searching for a long time without finding any solution for deploying my application as I wanted.

I'm developing a **Javafx** application under **maven** with **Eclipse**.
I'd like to :

- Deploy my application mainly on **windows** and **macOS**, and if possible on **linux**
- Have the **JRE bundled** with the **installer**, so that the user doesn't have to install java himself.
- The ability for the installer to detect an old version installed, overwrite it and **update** it with a new version of the installer.

I suppose this problem is less complicated on macOS, since everything is grouped together in an app that you simply replace in the App folder.

I'm starting to give up on this idea but I'd have liked to obfuscate the code too, but I couldn't do it because of a Proguard error.

I've already tried **jpackage** (for an .msi on windows) which I find very good, the problem is that it doesn't manage updates.

How do I plan to manage the update system in my software :

- The program launches
- if a new version is detected, a popup appears to inform the user of an update and its patch note
- the user can choose to skip the update or download it
- the software will download and run the new installer.

Do you know any tool that does what I'm looking for? I'm looking for a free or low-cost solution if possible.

Maybe I'm not thinking about the update system properly, and I'm open to any advice. But self-update solutions don't appeal to me because they can be too complicated to set up for me.

Also, I'm new in all the java things so my knowledge is limited.

Comment: Library recommendations are off-topic, but still, a quick google search brings up [updatefx](https://github.com/bitgamma/updatefx/tree/master).

Comment: Not what I asked for. It does exactly what my app already does. But still, thanks.

Comment: The question section "How do I plan to manage the update system in my software", describes exactly how updatefx works according to its [update process documentation](https://github.com/bitgamma/updatefx/tree/master#update-process), at least in my reading of it.  As I noted, recommendations are off-topic anyway, and the question would be closed and my comments deleted, [if they were moderated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389811/moderation-strike-stack-overflow-inc-cannot-consistently-ignore-mistreat-an), so just ignore the suggestion if it isn't useful to you.

Comment: "_Not what I asked for_" -- But that seems to be exactly what you asked for. Could you clarify?

Comment: This section was meant to provide some context. My question was about creating a installer/JRE bundle with detection of older versions. Sorry for the confusion.